# Type 'SNstorelocation' has no subscript members - I just don't understand

Tags: arrays, swift, subscript

I have been happily programming in Swift for a few weeks - really enjoying it, but I have hit a block. I have googled and I cannot find an explanation. I set up a much simpler test case, which didn't have the same problem.

I am getting the error "Type 'SNstorelocation' has no subscript members", and also "Value of type '[SNstorelocation]?' has no member 'append'".

I have read plenty about subscripting, but I don't think that is the problem. I want to have an array of structs, one of the elements is also an array of structs. I have seen it everywhere and my little test case it worked no problem.

So I have concluded (maybe incorrectly!) that somehow I haven't created and array. If I had, it should have an index to access the data and the code should work, but it doesn't.

Here is the little example I created, which I see as the same as my example, but simpler, which works.

struct test1 {
        var t1Item1: Int?
        var t1Item2: String?
        var myArray =  test2
    }
    struct test2 {
        var t2Item1: Int?
        var t2Item2: Int?

```
    init(v1: Int, v2: Int) {
        self.t2Item1 = v1
        self.t2Item2 = v2
    }
}
```

and I can do all the normal array things:

```
var myVar = [test1]()
var newItem = test1()
newItem.t1Item1 = 1
newItem.t1Item2 = "Hi"
myVar.append(newItem)
let myCount = myVar[0].myArray.count
```

Where as my example (just a few elements from the struct removed to keep it simple and short)

```
struct SNStoreItemGroups: Codable {
    var Welland: [SNStoreItem]
    var Other: [SNStoreItem]

    init() {
        self.Welland = []
        self.Other = []
    }
}
struct SNStoreItem: Codable {

    var locations =  [SNstorelocation]()
    var customerName: String?
    var customerPhone: String?
    var customerEmail: String?
    var notes: String?


}
struct SNstorelocation: Codable {
    let longitude: Double
    let latitude: Double
    let country: String
    let user: Int
    let timestamp: Double = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    init(_ lon: Double, _ lat: Double, _ ISOcountry: String, _ UserID: Int) {
        self.longitude = lon
        self.latitude = lat
        self.country = ISOcountry
        self.user = UserID
    }
}

var mySNData: SNStoreItem?
var SNStore: SNStoreItemGroups = SNStoreItemGroups()
// Some code to populate the SNStore



if let locIndex = SNStore.Welland[index].locations.index(where: { $0.longitude == MyLongitude }) {
    // This then causes the error
    // "Type 'SNstorelocation' has no subscript members"
                        if SNStore.Welland[index].locations[locIndex].timestamp {

                        }
                        }
```

Could someone please explain why this second example has no subscripts and the first one works OK? I just don't understand - especially because of the first let which seems to be OK in finding the index - I am sure I have just done something stupid!

TIA.

Comment: My first bit of advice is to make sure all variables/properties start with lowercase letters and to leave off any class prefix in their names (or make it clear in some other way that it isn't a class). Specifically, I would change `var SNStore: SNStoreItemGroups` to `var store: SNStoreItemGroups` then on the later lines it will look less like you are accessing a class property.

Comment: The second thing I would do is consolidate the two times you have a long chain of properties; try `let locations = store.welland[index].locations`. That will save you some text and allow you to check what the type is to make sure it is what you expect. Based on the error you are getting you are working with a `SNStoreLocation` not a `[SNStoreLocation]` (note the lack of square brackets in the message indicating you are not dealing with an array).

Comment: HI Thank you, I like the advice about the names and the classes, I had started to find that was getting confusing. I will go through the project and change them all I think before I carry on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambiguous error reporting by the Swift compiler…

A `timestamp` is not a Boolean so you need to compare the timestamp with something.

```
if let locIndex = mySNStore.welland[index].locations.index(where: { $0.longitude == 0.1234 }) {

    if mySNStore.welland[index].locations[locIndex].timestamp == Double(42) {

    }

}
```

You can see the correct error and the problem with:

```
let location = mySNStore.welland[index].locations[locIndex]
if location.timestamp {

}
```

You could raise a bug with the Swift team on this.

And as a style point Capitalised variables are horrible to read because they look like class names.

Comment: Bingo! I see the correct error now! That is very confusing. I might just go and raise a bug for this. I'll post the solution and error below in case someone is having the same problem. Thank you.